# C# Array: Order By Descending, including null values

Tags: c#, arrays, null, sql-order-by

I have an array of (always 4) objects, which I need to order by descending value of an object member.
I had thought to order it as

```
Array = Array.OrderByDescending(p => p.Val)
```

This fell over when one of the values was null, of course. So what I am aiming for, but my LINQ is not up to, is:

```
Array = Array.OrderByDescending(p => if( p != null ) p.Val; else float.MinValue)
```

How can I accomplish this ordering without having to delete and later re-add the null value? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm confused, Array is the name of the variable or the type name? Could you avoid this?

Comment: @Steve I think it's a property, but is poorly named (to say the least)!

Comment: Names have been changed for privacy, and (I thought) legibility.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the ternary conditional operator:

```
Array = Array.OrderByDescending(p => p != null ? p.Val : float.MinValue)
```

Per the comments below, the reason you can't use the `if/else` is because the body of the lambda (the stuff to the right of `p =>`) must be an expression, unless you surround the whole thing with curly braces.  So to illustrate, you *could* also use the `if/else` if you wanted:

```
Array = Array.OrderByDescending(p => 
{
    if (p != null) return p.Val; 
    else return float.MinValue;
});
```

But clearly more verbose.

Comment: p.Val is fine, as it is what I asked with.
Bonus points if you can also explain why this works, and an If/else doesn't. (I though this was just an old c-style way of writing an if statement)

Comment: This works because it's a single line.  The if-else would've been fine in curly braces.

Comment: @AustinSalonen, I originally tried it in curly braces, and it didn't work, hence the question. Unless you can show how exactly that would look?...

Comment: @KirkWoll, Perfect thank you. I had been missing the return, due to not fully understanding how the LINQ statements work. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what objects/types you're working with, but perhaps try a ternary operator like the following:

```
Array = Array.OrderByDescending(p => p == null ? float.MinValue : p.Val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this operator:

```
Array = Array.OrderByDescending( p => p ?? float.MinValue)
```